# Secure Computation and polynomial evaluation

Tags: polynomials

Consider we evaluate a polynomial P of degree d on some points (say 2d+1 points) to obtain Y's. 
My questions are: 
A) Given 2d+1 (or more) Y's can anybody 
   1) recover the original polynomial
   2) or even find a few roots of this polynomial?

B) If we have the second distinct polynomial P2 with the same degree as before, and evaluate it on the same points as before to obtain Z's.
   1) Given Y's and Z's recover the original polynomials
   2) or even find a few roots of these polynomials?

I`ll be pleased if you give me a logical reason for any answer or refer me to any theorem.
** We only give away the Y's values not X's.

Comment: I need to emphasis that "only" Y's are given away not X's.

Comment: Why? Can you refer me to any proof, please? What about partial information about the original polynomial, for instance can anybody deduce some roots (or even a root) of this polynomial from this points?

Answer (score 0):

If you are also given the points at which $P$ is evaluated, then you can recover $P$ from just $d+1$ pairs.

If only the values are given, then it cannot be done, not even for $d=1$, because all polynomials of degree 1 have the same set of values.

Explicitly: given $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$, take $P(x)=x+b$ and $x_i=y_i-b$, with $b$ chosen at will. Then, $P(x_i)=y_i$ but you cannot recover $b$. In particular, you cannot recover the root at $x=-b$.

Bottom line: no set of values determine a polynomial.

Comment: For two polynomials evaluated at same points, the Y values can be multiplied and we can recover the polynomial multiplication from these points. But if we use the scheme you stated, we cannot multiply the Y values and recover the product of two polynomials. Thus my main concern is to keep all roots of polynomial hidden but we can perform multiplication on the points. Also I'm wondering if there is any way ( given only Y's) to recover the roots (even one root) without constructing the polynomial?